# ORPort NoAdvertise & NoListen Not Working

Tags: tor-install

I'm having issues when implementing the NoAdvertise & NoListen options of the ORPort directive and am hoping someone here might be able to point me in the right direction.

I can get Tor to successfully work as a relay without using the NoAdvertise & NoListen options of the ORPort directive, but for certain reasons I need to configure Tor on a Private Address.

#### ORPort WITHOUT NoAdvertise & NoListen (SUCCEEDS)

Note: Successful Self-testing logs WITHOUT NoAdvertise & NoListen

```
Aug 13 00:26:42.000 [notice] Self-testing indicates your ORPort 198.91.60.78:443 is reachable from the outside. Excellent. Publishing server descriptor.
Aug 13 00:27:49.000 [notice] Performing bandwidth self-test...done.
```

Note: Successful Self-testing torrc WITHOUT NoAdvertise & NoListen

```
# cat /tmp/torrc 
Nickname ASUSWRTMerlinRelay
ORPort 198.91.60.78:443
SocksPort 9050
SocksPort 192.168.0.1:9050
ControlPort 9051
ExitRelay 0
DirCache 0
MaxMemInQueues 192 MB
GeoIPFile /opt/share/tor/geoip
Log notice file /tmp/torlog
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 192.168.0.1:9040
DNSPort 192.168.0.1:9053
RunAsDaemon 1
DataDirectory /tmp/tor/torrc.d/.tordb
AvoidDiskWrites 1
User tor
ContactInfo tor-operator@your-emailaddress-domain
```

Note: Nyx shows Tor build the initial 5 measurement circuits and then successfully continues to build new circuits

```
# nyx
nyx - 192.168.0.1 (Linux 2.6.36.4b...)  Tor 0.4.5.7 (recommended)
ASUSWRTMerlinRelay - 198.91.60.78:443, Control Port (open): 9051
cpu: 30.4% tor, 62.1% nyx  mem: 53 MB (21.4%)  pid: 14372  uptime: 05:18
fingerprint: 02DD61E41B3739C629C5CF8CEBA6000290BC3E7B
flags: Fast, Running, Valid
page 2 / 5 - m: menu, p: pause, h: page help, q: quit
Connections (807 outbound, 9 circuit, 1 control):
```

Note: Openssl s_client is successfully CONNECTED to the Public Address

```
# openssl s_client -connect 198.91.60.78:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = www.uy24fd6wkrzss.net
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = www.uy24fd6wkrzss.net
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/CN=www.uy24fd6wkrzss.net
  i:/CN=www.bu5cm42gttwqzick.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=www.uy24fd6wkrzss.net
issuer=/CN=www.bu5cm42gttwqzick.com
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1058 bytes and written 428 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: BC7B6CA79A1466768EAE37C7D591FB57F2D351E75B4C43AB16C8B8CBCBEB8E4BA4EDE2FEED8D4036D045F42F3F029585
    Key-Arg  : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1628842910
    Timeout  : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
```

However, Tor fails to work as a relay using the NoAdvertise & NoListen options of the ORPort directive; even though, Openssl s_client is successfully CONNECTED to the Public Address.

#### ORPort WITH NoAdvertise & NoListen (FAILS)

Note: Failed Self-testing logs WITH NoAdvertise & NoListen

```
Aug 13 01:01:46.000 [notice] Now checking whether IPv4 ORPort 198.91.60.78:443 is reachable... (this may take up to 20 minutes -- look for log messages indicating success)
Aug 13 01:21:45.000 [warn] Your server has not managed to confirm reachability for its ORPort(s) at 198.91.60.78:443. Relays do not publish descriptors until their ORPort and DirPort are reachable. Please check your firewalls, ports, address, /etc/hosts file, etc.
```

Note: Failed Self-testing torrc WITH NoAdvertise & NoListen

```
# cat /tmp/torrc 
Nickname ASUSWRTMerlinRelay
ORPort 198.91.60.78:443 NoListen
ORPort 192.168.0.1:9001 NoAdvertise
SocksPort 9050
SocksPort 192.168.0.1:9050
ControlPort 9051
ExitRelay 0
DirCache 0
MaxMemInQueues 192 MB
GeoIPFile /opt/share/tor/geoip
Log notice file /tmp/torlog
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 192.168.0.1:9040
DNSPort 192.168.0.1:9053
RunAsDaemon 1
DataDirectory /tmp/tor/torrc.d/.tordb
AvoidDiskWrites 1
User tor
ContactInfo tor-operator@your-emailaddress-domain
```

Note: Confirmed that the necessary PortForward between the Public & Private Addresses is in place

```
# iptables -A VSERVER -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1:9001
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 9001 -j ACCEPT
```

Note: Nyx shows Tor build the initial 5 measurement circuits, but after some time fails and only shows the outbound & control connections.

```
# nyx
nyx - 192.168.0.1 (Linux 2.6.36.4b...)  Tor 0.4.5.7 (recommended)
ASUSWRTMerlinRelay - 192.168.0.1:9001, Control Port (open): 9051
cpu: 10.6% tor, 3.2% nyx  mem: 55 MB (22.2%)  pid: 5374  uptime: 56:32
fingerprint: 02DD61E41B3739C629C5CF8CEBA6000290BC3E7B
flags: Fast, Running, Valid
page 2 / 5 - m: menu, p: pause, h: page help, q: quit
Connections (2289 outbound, 1 control):
```

Note: However, Openssl s_client is successfully CONNECTED to the Public Address

```
# openssl s_client -connect 198.91.60.78:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = www.uy24fd6wkrzss.net
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = www.uy24fd6wkrzss.net
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/CN=www.uy24fd6wkrzss.net
  i:/CN=www.bu5cm42gttwqzick.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=www.uy24fd6wkrzss.net
issuer=/CN=www.bu5cm42gttwqzick.com
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1058 bytes and written 428 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: BC7B6CA79A1466768EAE37C7D591FB57F2D351E75B4C43AB16C8B8CBCBEB8E4BA4EDE2FEED8D4036D045F42F3F029585
    Key-Arg  : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1628842910
    Timeout  : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
```

What am I missing?  Am I implementing the NoAdvertise & NoListen options of the ORPort directive incorrectly?

Thank you for your assistance.

Respectfully,

Gary

Comment: Do you have apropriate forwarding rule in your firewall to allow forwarding to your tor relay? DNAT rule by itself may be insufficient (depending on your forwarding chain policy and configuration).

Comment: @Tomek I believe the DNAT rule is sufficient as I am able to connect with openssl s_client via the Public Address. It seems to be something specific with the NoAdvertise & NoLIsten configuration. I appreciate the suggestion, though.

Comment: Not necessarily. Do you have any rules which apply to the above-mentioned public address which do not apply to the whole Internet address space?

Comment: @Tomek It appears that when Tor is bound directly to the Public Address:Port, the initial measurement connections are initiated from External Tor Nodes via High-Ports to the Public Address:Port over TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3 successfully passing self-test. However, when Tor is bound to the Private Address:Port and Advertising the Public Address:Port, the initial measurement connections are initiated from External Tor Nodes via High-Ports to the Public Address:Port over TLSv1.0. Tor does not like the TLSv1.0 connections and Resets them; thus, failing the self-test.

 Any fix for TLSv1.0 connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tomek

The solution was to include an ACCEPT Rule in the INPUT Chain as the PortForward destination was to the Private Gateway Address (192.168.0.1:9001).

```
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 9001 -j ACCEPT
```

The Tor Self-Test is returning successfully, now.

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Respectfully,

Gary